# Javascript render partial which is construct by a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, partial-views

So here is my situation

I got 2 folders, 1 is items and 1 is partials
Folder items:

```
-items
 -index.js.erb
```

Folder partials:

```
-partials
 -lists
  - _items.erb
```

in my index.js.erb under items folder, I want to will do javascript

```
$('#item').html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'partials/lists/items') %>");
```

So,I having an error which is 
The partial name (partial: `&#x27;partials/lists/items&#x27;`) is not a valid Ruby identifier, the errors something like that.

So,actually the situation is due to `partials/lists/_items.erb , _items.erb` is not _items.html.erb, but what I did is I'm create a function in application_helper to render my lists of object.  So, every different models I could render the same layout.

My question, how my index.js.erb able to render the partials correctly. I tried changed it into _items.html.erb ,but it appearing the same error to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try embedding it as a string like so:

```
$('#item').html("#{escape_javascript(render :partial => '/partials/lists/items')}");
```

Comment: hmmm, no luck, it dont work for me, it giving same error for me.

Comment: Did you use the syntax above i.e.`:partial =>`?

Comment: yea, tats fine now , but it print the code in the html, and not showing anything although it dont give me errors.

Comment: @Nich In your question above, can you show the code that is now inserted in the HTML? What do you expect to see on the web page?

Comment: erm, actually, when I do it my own way ,which is the default way, it success edy, just that when I check my responde after the js fired, it should only render the javascript , but now it render whole page include the javascript render data. Any idea?

Comment: Are you using an ajax call or specifying `:remote => true` in the link to rails?